# python: function occasionally returns Nonetype when returning one of its paramters?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm writing a scrolling list window widget in pygame (I know, its stupid, I admit it. But I had fun doing it) Anyway this function is threaded by an file-viewer object which passes an instance of itself along with an absolute path, addr, to display the contents of.

it starts by collecting the names of the files, and storing them in a 2 member array with the name of the file as the first instance and a formatted message to display on screen as the second member:

example: `["videos","[34]: D -- videos"]`

the functions busy waits for the user to click on one of the tiles as his/her input: `obj.waitingForReply`. `obj.Answer` stores the tuple of the panel the user clicked on. If it stores a directory, the function is supposed to call itself to view the contents of the directory, if its a file, the function exits and the thread ends by setting `obj.Quit` to true. This also kills the instance of fileviewer, as its purpose is to provide a GUI for the user to pick a file to read into the program. It immediately crashes whenever I go into another directory, but then choose to leave and return to the previous parent directory by choosing: `Back: [1]: D -- Desktop` As displayed when I choose another directory to view.

I'm looking into using a queue for the semaphores but I don't think that is my problem

code:

```
def listdirectory(obj,addr,prev=False,type="D",error=0):
    var=0
    choose = 1
    yesnext=False
    yesprev=False
    next=0
    print "in listdirectory"
    while(obj.Quit==False):
        mylist = []
        if(prev!=False):
            yesprev=True
            what = "F"
            if(os.path.isdir(prev)):
                what="D"
            m = re.split("\/",prev)
            mylist.append([prev, format1(choose,what,m[(len(m)-1)],1)])
            choose+=1
        if(yesnext):
            what = "F"
            if(os.path.isdir(next)):
                what="D"
            m = re.split("\/",next)
            mylist.append([next, format1(choose,what,m[(len(m)-1)],0)])
            choose+=1
        for items in os.listdir(addr):
            what = "F"
            check = concat(concat(addr,"/"),items)
            if(os.path.isdir(check)):
                what="D"
            m = re.split("\/",items)
            mylist.append([items, format2(choose,what,m[(len(m)-1)])])
            choose+=1

        print "listdirectory, currDrawing spinlock"
        while obj.currDrawing:
            var = (var+1)%2
        obj.currDrawing=True
        obj.loaddir(mylist)
        obj.currDrawing=False
        obj.waitingForReply=True
        while obj.waitingForReply:
            var = (var+1)%2
        if(obj.Answer!=False):
            chkprev = re.split("\/",addr)
            apath = concat(concat(addr,"/"),obj.Answer[0])
            if(obj.Answer[0]==chkprev[(len(chkprev)-2)]):
                return addr
            elif(os.path.isdir(apath)):
                yesnext=True
                next = listdirectory(obj,apath,addr)
                print "value of next: %r" % next
                next = re.split("\/",next)
                next = next[(len(next)-1)]
            else:
                obj.Quit=True
        choose=1
```

when it crashes:

```
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/threading.py", line 486, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/threading.py", line 446, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jason/Desktop/cup-robot-project/cup-robot-3/src/fileopener.py", line 524, in listdirectory
    next = re.split("\/",next)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 165, in split
    return _compile(pattern, 0).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Just to clarify: The `return addr` is for use of the calling previous listdirectory function. When it exits the function isn't supposed to return anything, as the desired variable is stored in `self.Answer` which gets accessed through one of the objects member functions. the entire function is technically a daemon: `while self.Quit==False` IDK if that changes anything

Comment: What is stopping it from reaching the end of that function? There is no `return` statement at the end of the function, so unless the line `if(obj.Answer[0]==chkprev[(len(chkprev)-2)]):` is true it will always return `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `return` statement in the function is:

```
        if(obj.Answer[0]==chkprev[(len(chkprev)-2)]):
            return addr
```

If this condition is not true, and the following statement `os.path.isdir(apath)` is not True, it will reach the line `obj.Quit=True`, leave the for loop, then reach the end of the function, where there is no `return`. At that point it will return `None`.

Comment: The function itself is sort of a daemon: it runs an infinite loop until told to quit by self.Quit or it calls itself or returns to a calling instance of itself

Comment: @jasondancks it will quit when the line `obj.Quit=True` happens. Is the problem that that is happening when you don't expect it to?

Comment: This entire function is screwed up. It provides inconsistent behavior. I'll rewrite this and get back to you. I'll give it to you anyway. Other than a queue I wonder if there is a better way of doing this. One thread waits for another thread to respond. They both quit and exit when prompted to do so.